# How to access a dropdown list control id in action of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdownlistfor

I want to implement a function which is already written in asp.net application of my colleague.I want to implement the same logic in asp.net mvc
but i don't know how to get the id of a dropdownlist control in action of a controller
What he has done is he is population a dropdwonlist by calling a function shown below

```
Global.BindRigionByApplicationAccess(drpRegion,
                                     ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"],
                                     ref ErrorMessage);
```

here 'drpRegion' is id of dropdownlist , in asp.net just a simple call will of that function will load data.

I did following code in asp.net mvc

in view

```
@Html.DropDownList("REGION_CODE", (SelectList)ViewBag.gpregions)
```

Comment: Not clear what your asking. Are you wanting to get the selected value of the dropdown when you post back, or do you want to preselect an option when you first render the view?

Comment: I don't think you can use `Global.BindRigionByApplicationAccess` method in asp.net mvc. Controllers aren't supposed to know anything about html controls. Can you add the code of `Global.BindRigionByApplicationAccess` method? If we know what that method does, perhaps we can recreate a similar method that works in MVC.

Comment: @ekad i udated my question

Comment: @peter, why did you delete the previous code in your question? Other people will be confused when reading my answer without seeing your previous code. They won't have any idea where the query comes from. If you don't mind, please rollback to the previous version to make other people understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the dropdown control to `LoadDropDown` method since controllers don't know anything about the html controls. What you need to do is the following:

1. Get the data from database.
2. Generate an instance of `List<SelectListItem>` based on the data.
3. Pass the instance of `List<SelectListItem>` to the view
4. Use the instance of `List<SelectListItem>` as the second parameter of `@Html.DropDownList` helper method in the view.

Let's start with `DataAccessLib` class. I would create the following method that returns a `Dictionary<string, string>`

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetDropdownItems(string sQuery, string sDTextField, string sDValueField)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    using (OracleConnection odConn = new OracleConnection(sConnStr))
    {
        odConn.Open();
        OracleCommand odCmd = odConn.CreateCommand();
        odCmd.CommandText = sQuery;
        using (var dr = odCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                dict[dr[sDValueField].ToString()] = dr[sDTextField].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    return dict;
}
```

then create the below method in `Global` class. Basically it sets the query, calls the above method, and generates an instance of `List<SelectListItem>`

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetRegionDropdownItems(string ApplicationId, ref string ErrorMessage)
{
    string query = @"SELECT distinct GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN Region_Code,
    R1.REGION_NAME FROM GP_REGION INNER JOIN GP_REGION R1 
    ON GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN = R1.REGION_CODE WHERE GP_REGION.REGION_HAS_DATA='Y'
    AND GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN IN (SELECT DISTINCT AR.BRANCH_CODE FROM PORTAL.UA_APPLN_ROLE AR 
    INNER JOIN PORTAL.UA_GROUP G ON AR.GROUP_CODE = G.GROUP_CODE
    WHERE G.USER_ID = '" + Global.UserId() + "' AND AR.APPLICATION_ID = '" + ApplicationId + "') ORDER BY GP_REGION.REGION_MAIN";

    // get the regions from database
    DataAccessLib dal = new DataAccessLib(Global.ConnectionString());
    Dictionary<string, string> regions = dal.GetDropdownItems(query, "REGION_NAME", "Region_Code");

    // generate the dropdown items
    List<SelectListItem> ddlItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var key in regions.Keys)
    {
        ddlItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Selected = false, Text = regions[key], Value = key });
    }

    return ddlItems;
}
```

then call `Global.GetRegionDropdownItems` and set the results to `ViewBag.Regions` in your controller

```
public ActionResult _GetRegions()
{
    List<SelectListItem> ddlItems = Global.GetRegionDropdownItems(
                                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"],
                                        ref ErrorMessage);
    ViewBag.Regions = ddlItems;

    return PartialView();
}
```

and finally use the `@Html.DropDownList` helper method in your view as below

```
@Html.DropDownList("REGION_CODE", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Regions)
```

Comment: you are brilliant ,you have manipulated my project and your guesses were correct.One question i would like to ask you is here Global.UserId() will return Httpcontext.current.session ["userid"] ,will this work in asp.net mvc?

Comment: I guess it will work, have you tried to debug inside `GetRegionDropdownItems` method and see if `Global.UserId()` returns the correct value?

Answer (score 2):

you can't access a dropdownlist within a controller action. please learn more about the MVC pattern: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

You need to create a list of the data you want to bind and pass the data to the view by returning it:

```
return View(myDataViewModel);
```

After that you are able to create a dropdownlist with that data.

See also: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views